# Calendar in javascript/ajax, php, and mysql?

Tags: php, ajax, calendar

I need to create a calendar which will allow people to view appointments and edit these. Am aware there are many out there put I have to create my own and it has to be my own code, so anything like jQuery is out of the question. I have studied Google Calendar and although I don't want it as advanced as this something similar should do.

I have a basic idea how to do it, but I don't quite know how to get the correct days in the month etc? I was thinking about an array in php, I don't know if the php `date()` function would help me here?

Has anyone created there own or have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I expect you will be using `date()` alot, along with `strtotime()` to calculate dates in the past/future. You will only need jQuery or similar if you want to provide some inline interactivity, ie let the user do various tasks without reloading the page. If you don't want to do that they can always reload the page for every action.

Comment: Hi, thanks wouldn't it be possible to have interaction using javascript and ajax alone without any libary?

Comment: everything you can do with jQuery, you can do without it as well, as jQuery is *just* a javascript library. It will be a lot more work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in PHP to get the number of days in a certain month: [`cal_days_in_month()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)